# Accessing $(this) within a callback function

Tags: jquery

I'm working on changing prompt() to jPrompt() since IE blocks prompt() from running.  The problem is $(this) no longer works correctly because jPrompt() doesn't return a value, but uses a callback function.

So lets say I have something like this, which works:

```
$("a.foo").click(function(){
    $(this).text(prompt("Type Something",""));
}
```

When I convert it to this it breaks:

```
$("a.foo").click(function(){
    jPrompt("Type something:","","", function(r) {
        $(this).text(r);
    }
}
```

How do I access $(this) properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("a.foo").click(function(){
    var that = this;
    jPrompt("Type something:","","", function(r) {
        $(that).text(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a closure:

```
$("a.foo").click(
  function(){
    var self = this;
    return function() {
      jPrompt("Type something:", "", "", function(r) { 
        $(self).text(r); 
      });
    }
  }()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to access the 'r' as an element. jPrompt is going to pass the text entered as 'r'.

```
$("a.foo").click(function(){
    jPrompt("Type something:","","", function(r){
        alert(r); //This will show the text entered.
    });
});
```