# Accessing variable in callback function... what?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been through a ton of posts and I finally got what I needed thanks to this:

```
$("a.foo").click(function(){
    var that = this;
    jPrompt("Type something:","","", function(r) {
        $(that).text(r);
    }
}
```

From the following:
[Accessing $(this) within a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825117/accessing-this-within-a-callback-function)

I was wondering if someone could expand on what exactly is happening here (why is `this` not available without re-assigning?) and what core information I should read up on? From what I gather this might have something to do with closures... that's most of what I bumped into while searching around. Is that accurate?

In my case, I was looking to execute some code, then redirect once an ajax request completed. In the callback function I was running `$(this).attr("href")` which was returning undefined.

Comment: Look up **lexical scoping** and **dynamic scoping**. Most variables in JS are lexically scoped, but `this` is dynamically scoped.

Comment: You should read the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is assigned by javascript according to how a function is called.  So, it is the `jPrompt()` function that determines what value `this` will have in your callback when `jPrompt()` calls the callback.

So, unless jPrompt goes out of its way to keep the same value for `this` via some argument you passed in, it will likely have a different value.  As such, you can save it away for access within the callback as you've done.  This is a very common design pattern in javacscript callbacks.

FYI, some of the ways that `this` is assigned:

- `obj.method()` - `this` in `method()` will be set to `obj`
- `func.call(obj)` - `this` in `func()` will be set to `obj`
- `func()` - `this` will be set to `window` in `func()` or `undefined` in strict mode

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question with some added comments:

```
$("a.foo").click(function(){
    var that = this; //`this` holds the a object clicked.  now so does `that`! 
    jPrompt("Type something:","","", function(r) { 
        //even if `this` has a different value here, `that` still holds the a object clicked
        $(that).text(r);
    }
}
```

This is something you will often find yourself doing in similar situations.  `this` is context-dependent and you often need to keep the value `this` had in one context and use it in another.

A quote from the ECMAScript specification:

> #### 10.1.7 This
>
> There is a *this* value associated with
>   every active execution context. The
>   *this* value depends on the caller and
>   the type of code being executed and is
>   determined when control enters the
>   execution context.

Hope that answers your question.  You also asked for a resource for further reading. Please visit:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

These guys provide excellent documentation both detailed and typically quite accurate (unlike other popular sources of reference that often comes first in Google searches -- w3cshools.com I am thinking of you!).

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of `this` changes depending on where you're at. The `this` within a handler for your click event means something other than the `this` within the callback passed to your `jPrompt` function.

For what it's worth, you don't need to re-assign `this`, since the `event` object passed into your handler will have a reference to the `currentTarget`:

```
$("a.foo").on("click", function (event) {
    // 'this' here refers to the anchor we clicked
    jPrompt("Type something:", "", "", function (r) {
        // 'this' here refers to whatever jPrompt instructs
        $(event.currentTarget).text(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### A Short Overview of `this`

`this` in JavaScript is **dynamically scoped**. Its behavior differs from all other variables which are **lexically scoped**. Other variables don't have a different binding depending on *how* the function is called; their scope comes from *where* they appear in the script. `this` however behaves differently, and can have a different binding depending not on *where* it appears in the script but on *how* it's called. Consequently, it can be a source of confusion for people learning the language, but mastering it is necessary in order to become a proficient JavaScript developer.

Since `this` is dynamically bound there are several ways to change its values based on how you call the function.

---

### Examples

When you execute a function in JavaScript, the default `this` is `window`.

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this);
}

foo(); // => window
```

The `this` value can be changed in a number of ways. One way is to call the function as a method of an object:

```
var x = {
    foo: function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
};
x.foo(); // => This time it's the x object.
```

Another way is to use `call` or `apply` to tell the function to execute in the context of a certain object.

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this);
}
foo.call(x); // => x object again
foo.apply(x); // => x object as well
```

If you `call` or `apply` on `null` or `undefined`, the default behavior will occur again: the function will be executed in the context of `window`:

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this);
}
foo.call(null); // => window
foo.apply(undefined); // => window
```

However, note that in ECMAScript 5 **strict mode**, `this` does not default to window:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    function foo() {
        console.log(this);
    }

    foo(); // => undefined
    foo.call(null); // => null
    foo.apply(undefined); // => undefined

})();
```

You can also set the `this` by using `bind` to bind the function to an object before it is called:

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this);
}

var bar = {
    baz: 'some property'
};

var foobar = foo.bind(bar);

foobar(); // => calls foo with bar as this
```

---

### Going Father: Lazy Bind / Uncurrying `this`

Going further, you may sometimes want to take functions which act on a `this` and allow the `this` value to be passed in as the first argument to the function. This can be really helpful for Array methods, such as `forEach`. For instance, let's say you are dealing with an object which is array-like but not actually an array.

```
var arrayLike = {
    '0': 'a',
    '1': 'b',
    '2': 'c',
    'length': 3
};
```

If you want to iterate over this object with `forEach`, you could use `call`:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(arrayLike, function(item) {
    console.log(item);
});
// Logs: a, b, c
```

However, another option is to create a `forEach` function which can be called directly on your object:

```
var forEach = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.forEach);
```

Now you can use this function anytime you want to iterate over an array-like object:

```
forEach(arrayLike, function(item) {
    console.log(item);
});
// Logs: a, b, c
```

Sometimes this method is referred to as "uncurrying `this`". However, I prefer to create a function which can generate these "uncurried" functions and call it "lazy binding".

```
var lazyBind = Function.prototype.bind.bind(Function.prototype.call);

var forEach = lazyBind(Array.prototype.forEach);
var slice = lazyBind(Array.prototype.slice);
var map = lazyBind(Array.prototype.map);

forEach(arrayLike, function(u) {
    console.log(u);
});
// Logs: a, b, c

var realArray = slice(arrayLike);
// Converts arrayLike into a real array

forEach(
    map(arrayLike, function(u) {
        return u + 'Q';
    }),
    function(u) {
        console.log(u);
    }
);
// Logs: aQ, bQ, cQ
```

One really awesome thing about this technique is it can be useful for creating securable JavaScript, which can be helpful if you don't want other scripts on the page snooping around your internal variables. This is a pretty advanced meta-programming technique, though, and you don't see it in day-to-day JavaScript.