# How to get arguments of a function that created a function from the created function

Tags: javascript, reverse-engineering, malware

The problem is hard to describe, so i will try my best.

I need to reverse a obfuscated javascript which is using code flow obfuscation, data transformation and some others methods.
In this code, the program is saving some functions to use them in the flow.
These functions are created by calling a specific function and i need to get arguments of this specific function by using the created function (these arguments are important to predict the stack flow)

Here is an example :

```
function createFunction(arg){
    return function(){
        'use strict';
        // Do some things with arg
        return true;
    }
}
var func = createFunction(5);
// Need to get the argument 5 of createFunction from func var
var bool = func();
```

NB: The returned function is in strict mode

I don't know if it's even possible, i tried a lot of things, checked every prototype or property etc..

Thanks.

---

Edit :

This is not possible without editing any code, closures and lexical scoping in javascript is really strict, in my case, i just made a breakpoint after the function declaration, then i overwrited the function himself by adding prototype to the returned function with parameters.

```
function createFunction(arg){
    var fn = function(){
        'use strict';
        // Do some things with arg
        return true;
    }
    fn.prototype.arg = [arg];
    return fn;
}
var func = createFunction(5);
var arg = func.prototype.arg; // 5 is here now
var bool = func();
```

Here is a good explanation : [JS: Nested functions gain a copy of the outer function's parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784998/js-nested-functions-gain-a-copy-of-the-outer-functions-parameters)

Also some docs : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: You mean the 5, for example?

Comment: @EmilioGrisolía Yes sir

Comment: Well, as far as I know, the arguments are only accessible from the function that's called (or functions defined inside it). I can only think about adding the arguments as a property.
I mean, like `createFunction.arg = arg` and then you can access it via `createFunction.arg`.

Comment: I cannot edit the code himself, because it is only running on a specific domain, with specific element on the page and also counting every single ponctuations before running etc.. Which mean that i can only analysis the code flow with watch expressions for now so i have only access to the variable, but i don't have any control on that. But i'm not surprised that this isn't possible, the obfuscation himself is really well thought.

Comment: If you cannot change the code, it is indeed impossible. Local variables are private, and JS has pretty good security guarantees on that.

Comment: (Your only chance would be to overwrite `createFunction` before it is getting called, and intercept the argument)

Comment: @Bergi Oh yeah, that's a good solution in my case, i didn't think about that, i can break early in the code before anything run then overwrite `createFunction` to add prototype to the returned function that contains the parameters.
Indeed javascript have good closures and scope, i looked around a lot before asking. Thanks a lot, i will edit my question ;)